# im new to programming and i cant find why this code is not working like i want it to work

Tags: python, if-statement

the problem is with the is_tall >> 175 for some reason it just keeps printing that he isn't tall even if I input a number bigger than 175

```py
is_male = input("are you a male?: ")
is_tall =int(input("how tall are you: "))

if is_male == "yes" :
    is_male = True
else:
    is_male = False

if is_tall >> 175 :
    is_tall = True
else:
    is_tall = False

if is_tall and is_male :
    print("you are a male and you are tall")
elif not(is_tall) and is_male :
    print("you are a male but you are not tall")
elif is_tall and not(is_male) :
    print("you are not a male but you are tall")
elif not (is_male) and not (is_tall) :
    print("your are not a male nor tall")
```

Comment: `if is_tall > 175 :`

Comment: `200 >> 175` means `200 halved 175 times`, which evaluates to `0`, a falsy value. `200 > 175` (is `200` greater than `175`?) is something _very_ different.

Comment: FYI, `>>` is bitwise right shift operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is most probably due to the use of double > signs. >> signifies the right shift operation and does not imply greater than.

The below code works perfectly fine for your use case.

```
is_male = input("Are you male?")
is_tall = int(input("How tall are you?"))

if is_male == "yes":
  is_male = True
else:
  is_male = False

if is_tall>175: //You need to change this
  is_tall = True
else:
  is_tall = False

if is_tall and is_male :

  print("you are a male and you are tall")

elif not(is_tall) and is_male :

  print("you are a male but you are not tall")

elif is_tall and not(is_male) :

  print("you are not a male but you are tall")

elif not (is_male) and not (is_tall) :

  print("your are not a male nor tall")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`>>` is the "shift right" operator, not the "larger than" operator. Shifting any reasonable int right 175 times will produce 0 in a and therefore the condition will evaluate to false.

To make a long story short, you should use the `>` operator:

```py
if is_tall > 175 :
   # Here -^
```

As a side note, note that for boolean variables you don't really need this if-else structure, and make your code much shorter by assigning the result of the condition directly to a variable:

```py
is_male = (is_male == 'yes')
it_tall = (is_tall > 175)
```